# c# compiler directives use in a continuous delivery pipeline

Tags: c#, msbuild, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, compiler-directives

My team uses compiler directives to create different versions of our product for different stages (debug, test, release) but now we want to move a CI/CD strategy and we are discussing whether it is a good idea to use compiler directives at all since the artifact(s) produced for one configuration cannot be used for another, for example, our CI server runs the build process with the **test** configuration and all stages from the build process pass including UI automated tests, the artifacts created in this process cannot be deployed to production because for production the application needs to be compiled using the **release** configuration thus creating a new set of untested artifacts to deploy the production environment, which, in my opinion makes the work performed in the previous stage(s) obsolete because you probably want to run your tests against the newly created artifacts.

Has anyone had a similar similar situation and if so how did you address it with your team. Is it a good idea to use c# compiler directives when you want to move to a CI/CD strategy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We had a similar problem two years ago.  We were re-building our code for each environment (DEV, QA, MOCK, PROD) and in some cases check-ins would occur between environments and invalidate all our testing.  When we started our CD journey we knew we had to get to a build once/deploy many scenario.  We used MSDeploy to deploy all our code.  This includes web sites/services, windows services, scheduled tasks and SQL databases.

We place all environment differences in our config files and control the transformations via [Parameterization in MSDeploy](http://www.iis.net/learn/publish/using-web-deploy/web-deploy-parameterization). Parameterization is applied at deploy time. Setup consists of a parameters.xml file that defines what needs to be parameterized and a SetParameters.[environment].xml file for each environment with pertinent values for that enviornment.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I will look into this approach.